Quadrature encoder interface without capacitor
I have connected Digilent PmodENC board with a rotary shaft encoder to myRIO MXP DIO pin. MyRIO has an internal 40 kOhm pull-up resistor.
On PmodENC board each encoder output has 2 resistors with identical values, i.e. 4.7 kOhm pull-up and 4.7 kOhm series resistor (see figure, only one channel is shown).
The setup works fine, I am using FPGA based Encoder Express VI to dechipher encoder signals.
However, I have some questions regarding PmodENC design as I have not found any satisfactory explanation:

I am aware that recommended practice is to add RC filter to each channel to handle debouncing, however I am puzzled that PmodENC does not include any capacitors between channels and GND. What is then the reason to have series resistance R2?
Is there any assumption that stray capacitance is always large enough to form some sort of RC filter anyway?
Does this design with equal parallel and series resistances require another pull-up at uC input with significantly higher value than R1 and R2? Or it is meant to be used as such (without another pull-up at uC side)?


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

handle denouncing in software

R1 is obvious and R2 seems to me both protective (to the quad switches) and also perhaps to provide a semi-known/predictable output impedance (2:1, depending on output state is "close enough".) You may want to apply a Schmitt trigger. The 74AC14 or 74HC14 might be an example which also support the rail voltage you show. (And Digilent recommends either 3.3 or 5.0, as I gather from their web page.)
